# Knockout required field using JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using the knockoutjs mapping plugin to build a view model from JSON.  I then bind that model's properties to fields on my form.  The question is how can I make the fields in the model generated from JSON required?

For example if I load JSON like this:

```
$.getJSON('/Department/GetEmptyModel/', function (data) {
    var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    self.AddDepartmentModel(mapped);
});
```

And save it like this:

```
self.AddDepartmentModel.AddDepartment = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Department/Add/",
        type: 'post',
        data: ko.toJSON(self.AddDepartmentModel),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            self.ListOfDepartments.GetListOfAllDepartments();
        }
    });
};
```

How can I ensure that all the required fields are there before the save happens?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem a while back and this is how I solved it:

**Add a custom extender**

```
ko.extenders.spaceNotAllowed = function(target, options){
    target.hasError = ko.observable();
    target.validationMessage = ko.observable();
    var validate = function(newValue) {  // Validation for a field that shouldnt contain spaces
        if(value.indexOf(" ") === -1) target.hasError(false);
        else {
            target.hasError(true);
            target.validationMessage(target.hasError() ? options.errorMessage || "No spaces allowed" : "");
        }
    }
    validate(target());
    target.subscribe(validate);
    return target;       
}
```

In the ViewModel:

**Use the extender in my view model on fields that need the validation**

```
var ViewModel = {
    var self = this;
    self.noSpaces = ko.observable('initialValue').extend({spaceNotAllowed: {errorMessage: 'no spaces allowed'}});
}
```

**Option 1** Now, if you have a submit button on your html page, you can data-bind it like this:

```
<button type='button' data-bind='click: saveStuff, enable: !noSpaces.hasError'>Save</button>
```

This way, the 'save button' will only be enabled if the validation passes. I found this answer a while back when I had the same problem and when I was fairly new to knockout.

**Option 2**
CHeck if the fields are valid before AJAX:

```
if(self.noSpaces.hasError) {
    // Do something here
    return;
}
$.ajax(....);
```

This link explains how to use custom extenders in knockout: [Using extenders to augment observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate data before submitting it to the server. Look into validation plugin for Knockout: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

I hope this will help to solve the issue.